# Get title from a url from a server side Meteor method when the page content is compressed (gzip)

Tags: meteor, gzip

I want to create a routine to get the title given a url ─ outside my domain ─ using a server side Meteor method.

I'm using the following code:
'''

```
 var result = HTTP.get(url, {timeout:30000});
    if(result.statusCode==200) {
        console.log('OK status code 200 on libGetTitleFromUrlAsync');
        var content =  (result.headers['content-encoding'] === 'gzip')? inflateSync(new Buffer(result.content)) : result.content;
        var start = content.toLowerCase().indexOf('<title>');
        var end = content.toLowerCase().indexOf('</title>');
        var title = content.substring(start + '<title>'.length, end);
```

Im' using http and gb96:zlib packages. The first retrieves the ulr content and the second decompress the buffer if it's compressed.

I'm using this compressed page as a sample http://firstround.com/review/this-is-what-impactful-engineering-leadership-looks-like/

InflateSync keeps raising an exception.
Any idea? 
When the target url in not compressed it works perfectly.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Discover Meteor has a solution for this. I don't have access to it otherwise I would post.